# ¿Como puedo crear un nuevo array dentro de un loop en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

Estoy aprendiendo Javascript y quiero poder crear un array dentro de un ciclo for, esto quisiera aplicarlo a un objeto o a otro array segun las condiciones, sin embargo, no he podido lograrlo y solamente estoy agregando a la nueva variable el ultimo dato del ciclo. El codigo que estoy escribiendo es este:

```
var arrayPrueba = ['Uno', 'Dos', 'Tres'];
function func(arrayPrueba) {
    for(var i=0; i<arrayPrueba.length;i++) {
        var newArray = [];
            newArray.push(arrayPrueba[i]);
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

Comment: ¿Quieres recorrer tantas posiciones tiene el array y agregar en cada posicion del array el array que estas recorriendo?

Comment: coloca el array creado, afuera del for, encima para que se vaya almacenando en cada iteracion

Comment: @ANDYJOANTAIPELOPEZ Buen comentario. Deberias escribirle una respuesta, pues tu deducción es correcta, sino la pregunta puede quedar pendiente de respuesta eternamente o bien otro puede escribirla por ti. Gracias por colaborar en el buen funcionamiento del sitio (si lo haces, claro :-)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes colocar el array creado, afuera del for, encima para que se vaya almacenando en cada iteracion

```
function func(arrayPrueba) {
var newArray = []; // aqui
for(var i=0; i<arrayPrueba.length;i++) {
        newArray.push(arrayPrueba[i]);
}
return newArray;
}
```

Así no se sobrescribirá la variable con cada iteración del for, ya que esta afuera.

Comment: Tu respuesta es correcta, pero recomiendo incluyas una explicación sobre la razón del cambio.

Comment: @DavidSK Así esta bien?

Comment: El problema se encuentra en el Scope (alcance) de la variable. La variable existe en el bloque donde fue declarada.
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Comment: Efectivamente, un error de principiante. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

En cada iteracion del bucle estas definiendo de nuevo a la variable, es por eso que solo obtienes el ultimo valor. Puedes solucionarlo definiendo la variable fuera del bucle y dentro de este ir actualizando los valores de la variable

```
 var arrayPrueba = ['Uno', 'Dos', 'Tres'];
 var newArray = []; //Variable nueva

 function func(arrayPrueba) {
    for(var i=0; i<arrayPrueba.length;i++) {
            newArray.push(arrayPrueba[i]);
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

Otra opcion es definir la variable utilizando la funcion map

```
var newArray = arrayPrueba.map(valor => valor);
```